# Recovery Mode is not available for MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, recovery, recovery-hd

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2009 with El Capitan running on it.

I wanted to enter Recovery Mode and pressed <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appeared with a progress bar. After about 3 hours waiting the progress bar was complete but nothing happened. I waited another two hours but still nothing changed.

When booting in normal mode everything is fine and within a minute I can start working. Do you have any advice for me?

The diskutil output as requested by @LexS user87973:

```
macs-MBP:~ Fab$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *320.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            319.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Comment: Oh by the way I checked my hard drive in disk utility and there were no errors.

Comment: One question is have since it's a 2009 and drive replacement is a distinct possibility: running from a drive clone?

Comment: Go to Terminal (in Utilities), run `diskutil list` and paste the output into the question text please.

Comment: Try booting into internet recovery mode (cmd + option + R)

Comment: @NoahL  I also tried that option but with the same result

Comment: @LexSuser87973 I added the output above

Answer (score 1):

You can have a failing hard disk that shows no errors in Disk Utility. Not all hard disk crashes are due to head landing, they can be electronical components overheat, the electronic components fails gradually slowing down the disk speed to null in a few months. I suggest a disk clone and a swap.